# Mac OS X - Ventura - App Running, but it is not visible in any desktop

Tags: applications, desktop, ventura

I am running Mac OS X Ventura 13.4.1. Recently when I began to use an app, I could not find it any desktop, despite the icon appearing in the dock, and the app menu appearing on top left hand corner next to the apple icon (where the app menus appear). This is despite having  been able to successfully for a year on a variety of platforms (Mac OS, iPhone, iPad ).

I have tried:

1. Restarting the app
2. Restarting the machine
3. Deleting the app, and reinstalling it from the App Store
4. Trying to find the preferences file, but I could not identify it

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you saying that the app does not open any window? An app does not need to open a window when it starts - so it would be helpful if you were to name the app! Maybe one of its menus (e.g. File menu) is used to open something.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't open up any window. The app is Mattermost.

Comment: If you question relates just to Mattermost, I suggest you visit their support forums or your IT support team and ask about how to get started.

Comment: I don't think it does. I think that it is a Mac OS thing. I have used the app successfully for a year on a variety of platforms. Then it on once occasion I closed it and then tried to open it and I couldn't find it.  Actually I guess my problem description does not state that I have used it successfully before. I will add that.

Comment: actually the same behaviour is occurring with my Viber app so I am pretty sure it is OS related. I updated to 13.4.1 last week.

Comment: Check the Window menu. Some apps have only one window yet still behave as multi-window apps, meaning closing the window does not quit the app. You can check this on the Messages app, close the main message window, the app stays open. The winow menu shows only one option to re-open it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCB5u.png

Comment: All selections on the windows menu are grated out. Thanks for the suggestion nevertheless.

Comment: Can you create a new window with COMMAND-N (or COMMAND-1, etc...) ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @SteveChambers. The command yields no effect. I did notice one other things. When I select help from the mattermost menu, it is empty. In fact it just as the string (empty)

Comment: You may have to ask the developers of the software about this. It sounds like a problem with the app Mattermost.